# Monotonicity of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

If $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ then
$\int_a^b f \leq \int_a^b g.$

What I did i followed Bartle's method but I cannot keep up on what He meant.

This is the uniqueness so that we'll be familiar:

[S as "sum" and I'll just P' for P partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxFYn.png)

Referring to this:

$\left|S(f;P')-\int_a^bf\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $\left|S(g;P')-\int_a^bg\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ (1)

This was Bartle's method:

To prove the inequality, we note that the triangle inequality be applied to (1)

thus,

$\int_a^b f - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < S(f;P')$ and $S(g;P')<\int_a^b g + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $

If we use the fact that $S(f;P')\leq S(g;P')$ , we have

$\int_a^b f \leq \int_a^b g + \varepsilon$

But, since $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary number we conclude that $\int_a^b f \leq \int_a^b g$

Please help me to understand this, how it turned out to this it's simplified and there were no further details

Comment: I can help with the last bit reasoning. For real numbers $a$ and $b$, if $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $a\leq b$. Try to see why this is true. (Hint: Contrapositive)

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you instead prove that if $h\ge 0$, then $\int_a^b h(x)\,dx\ge 0$.